# myeclipse javascript: "jump to" function when clicking on function name not working

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

this is a question about the myecplise editor plugin for eclipse.

let's take this simple example:

1. not so pretty javascript (because namespace is cluttered)

   function blubb () {//do stuff}

   blubb();
2. prettier javascript (because we wrap it all in variable bla to not clutter the namespace)

   var bla = {
       blubb: function () {
           //do stuff
       }
   }

   bla.blubb();

if i press Ctrl and click on blubb() in example 1 i get taken to the function declaration. if i click on blubb() of the bla.blubb() part in example 2 i do NOT get taken to the function declaration. why??!? how can i fix it?

Comment: looks like it's a bug/missing functionality so the boys from myeclipse are on it: http://myeclipseide.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=127027#127027